# Shipping a C++ dll with only a C api exposed

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm writing a piece of software whose API is intended to be C only , because it is easy to link C code against other softwares/clients.

The actual program code however is done in C++, using all the usual C++ features like exception, STL, etc.

The exported API / headers themselves will be written in pure C, with the `export "C"` keywords.

What should I be wary of if I intend to deliver this dll to users who have no knowledge of C++ on their side? Normally they should not be concerned about the fact that the actual code is in C++, and only be required to know how to link against C code via a header file.
I've been told that I should ensure that libstd is linked statically, which may be not be possible on all platforms (there will be a linux and a windows build). How about exceptions ? etc

Comment: You might find this talk interesting on "Hourglass Interfaces for C++ APIs" which discusses issues around building a pure C API over a C++ library with C++ helper classes that sit on top as a header only API wrapper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y

Comment: If it's a C API you can't throw any exceptions; it's up to you to contain them and convert to a different error reporting mechanism.

Comment: @Alan Stokes  out of curiosity what happens if there's an uncaught exception ?

Comment: `std::string` gave me problems when doing this even when statically linked. I had some weird `ios_base` not initialized error when using the dll in a program written in C.. but when using the dll in a program written C++, it worked fine. Was something to do with static initializer.

Comment: The consumers will need to link their program with the C++ compiler, otherwise you probably won't get the correct semantics of initialization for the code within your library, or the correct support libraries linked.  If you're using C++, link with the C++ compiler.  On the whole, it will be best to compile the source files containing `main()` with a C++ compiler too, even if that `main()` is as trivial as `extern "C" int real_main(int argc, char **argv);` and `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return real_main(argc, argv); }` and the normal `main()` is renamed to `real_main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) wrap your header in:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

2) make opaque pointers:

```
struct myInternalStructFOO; // incomplete type
typedef struct myInternalStructFOO *cFOO; // public type

class myInternalClassBAR; // incomplete type
typedef class myInternalClassBAR *cBAR; // public type
```

you need not to give class definitions in your public api.
class definitions will go in some private headers.